# R-looping over rows to find windows

Tags: r, loops

Good day everyone

My apologies, I am not even sure how to put this! I have a SNP dataset with 4 columns (i.e., snp, bta, position, maf). Using R, I need a loop/chromosome (bta) to identify windows of 7 consecutive SNPs if maf<= 0.01. Once found, calculate the distance between the 1st and 7th SNP (position i+6-position i) if distance<=300 print the row. Start over in the 2nd chromosome, across all chromosomes

```
snp bta position  maf  
1    1   135098 0.00  
2    1   135198 0.01  
3    1   135200 0.00  
4    1   135220 0.01  
5    1   135225 0.00  
6    1   135230 0.01  
7    1   135235 0.01  
8    1   516404 0.27  
9    1   571340 0.02  
10   1   654413 0.07  
11   1   845494 0.44  
12   1   883895 0.42  
13   1   905632 0.00  
14   1   929617 0.20  
15   1   950841 0.20  
16   1   974586 0.04  
17   2  1078200 0.01  
18   2  1078256 0.00  
19   2  1078280 0.01  
20   2  1078300 0.00  
21   2  1078400 0.00  
22   2  1078410 0.01  
23   2  1078450 0.00
```

I wish to have something like below,

```
snp bta position  maf  
1    1   135098 0.00  
2    1   267940 0.01  
3    1   305793 0.00  
4    1   353745 0.01  
5    1   393248 0.00  
17   2  1009504 0.01  
18   2  1078256 0.00  
19   2  1114422 0.01  
20   2  1189382 0.00
```

I will greatly appreciate your help

Comment: In your question, you ask for assistance with identifying "windows of 7 consecutive SNP's if maf <= 0.01". Yet, in your table, you do not in fact have 7 consecutive rows that are less than the desired value.

Comment: Sorry, that was stupid of me I got limited by the example I used dataset as i expect only a few of those per chromosome. I also didn't confirm the distances. I will revise my data sets accordingly. Thank you

Comment: Will you provide a new dataset? it can be assumed that the window will be a constant of 7 rows?

Comment: Why row 13 is not there? Isn't `yourdf[yourdf$maf <= 0.01, ]` enough?

Comment: @PauloCardoso, I revised the dataset and output. In the 2nd data? Yes, row 13 is not there in the 2nd data because it would be too far distace-wise 905632-135098=770534. I need distance <=300

Comment: But it's not far from the 2nd window is it? Distances for all lines are obtained taking the 1st line as reference?

Comment: @PauloCardoso the 2nd window is on the 2nd chromosome (bta 2). I extract windows chromosome-wise.

Comment: @vrajs5, thank you. I always struggle to present my data nicely

Comment: @PauloCardoso, Exactly, distances are with respect to the first line in a window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking df data.frame as the data provided:

```
df <- read.table(text=readClipboard(), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F )
r <- rle(df$bta)
df$window <- unlist(lapply(r$lengths, seq_len))

df
   snp bta position  maf window
1    1   1   135098 0.00      1
2    2   1   135198 0.01      2
3    3   1   135200 0.00      3
4    4   1   135220 0.01      4
5    5   1   135225 0.00      5
6    6   1   135230 0.01      6
7    7   1   135235 0.01      7
8    8   1   516404 0.27      8
9    9   1   571340 0.02      9
10  10   1   654413 0.07     10
11  11   1   845494 0.44     11
12  12   1   883895 0.42     12
13  13   1   905632 0.00     13
14  14   1   929617 0.20     14
15  15   1   950841 0.20     15
16  16   1   974586 0.04     16
17  17   2  1078200 0.01      1
18  18   2  1078256 0.00      2
19  19   2  1078280 0.01      3
20  20   2  1078300 0.00      4
21  21   2  1078400 0.00      5
22  22   2  1078410 0.01      6
23  23   2  1078450 0.00      7

library(dplyr)
res <- df %>%
  group_by(bta) %>%
  mutate(dif = position - first(position)) %>%
  filter(maf <= 0.01, dif <= 300, window < 7)

res
Source: local data frame [12 x 6]
Groups: bta

   snp bta position  maf window dif
1    1   1   135098 0.00      1   0
2    2   1   135198 0.01      2 100
3    3   1   135200 0.00      3 102
4    4   1   135220 0.01      4 122
5    5   1   135225 0.00      5 127
6    6   1   135230 0.01      6 132
7   17   2  1078200 0.01      1   0
8   18   2  1078256 0.00      2  56
9   19   2  1078280 0.01      3  80
10  20   2  1078300 0.00      4 100
11  21   2  1078400 0.00      5 200
12  22   2  1078410 0.01      6 210
```

Comment: I think I follow your code as you group per chromosome, calc distance and condition the maf and distance. I just don't know where to fit mye object or data.frame! Please help @PauloCardoso.

Comment: Okay I did as follows

Comment: @Tumi2002 You'll have any incomplete windows?

Comment: @Tumi2002 I think I got it working considering the window of consecutive snp for each bta group. Verify?

Comment: I will be glad to verify that. Just installed dplyr. I tested your previous code and it seems the problem is with   w7 <- rep(1:7, times = 1214) where 8492 rows.   So I did 8492/7 and I get an error #install.packages('dplyr')  
> w7 <- rep(1:7, times = 1214)  
> mydata$w7 <- w7[1:nrow(mydata)]  
> library(dplyr)  
> mydata %>%  
+ group_by(mydata$bta) %>%  
+ mutate(dif = mydata$position - first(mydata$position)) %>% 
+ filter(mydata$maf <= 0.01, dif <= 300, w7 < 7)  
Error in list(snp = c(7297L, 1490L, 1588L, 512L, 6797L, 3553L, 3474L,  :   
  invalid subscript type 'integer'

Comment: @Tumi2002 I changed the code to accomodate a better way to create the window.

Comment: @Tumi2002 yes, w7 was changed to window. r <- rle(df$bta) and is also there. Sorry.

Comment: I tested the example file it works alright. One question how do I put the output into a datafile. Currently, it display on the console

Comment: @Tumi2002 I edited it accordingly. By assigning with `<-` the summary to an object, a data.frame is created

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked just fine. It was such a messy question. I am glad you got it. I will learn better next time